# word press: wp_users. Cannot access our website. Password is not resent.

Tags: wordpress

We may have been hacked as one of our links now goes to a dodgy site.
1. wp_users in our db: I checked our user_login, user_pass, user_email etc...
I use them to try and login to our wordpress account and it says one of them is incorrect would you like to reset password but we never receive anything in out inbox - not in junk mail, not anywhere etc...
As I say, in our db everything is correct.
How am I supposed to reagin my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the password directly in phpmyadmin but you will need to convert it to a md5 hash string first. Just google md5 hash generator and write a password to convert, then you can paste the converted string into the password field for the desired user in the database.

Then when you are logged in, change password in wp-admin to make sure everything works as it should.

Comment: No, wordpress uses Salted hashed passwords. Generating a "normal" MD5 won't work

Comment: Worth a try though, seems like WP has backwards compatibility and should auto-upgrade the password -> http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Thats why he needs to change the password again in wp-admin.

Comment: Stig was correct. Used an online tool, generated the hash, copied and paste in phoMyAdmin, logged in perfectly. A big thank you Stig.